# Why can't I upload the dSYM of my new app to HockeyApp?

Tags: ios, fastlane, hockeyapp

After successfully uploading the app to iTunes, the upload of the dSYM to hockey is failing with the following message?

```
Error when trying to upload ipa to HockeyApp: {"status"=>"error", "message"=>"Bundle version is blank or could not be parsed. Please check the file format of your symbols file."}
```

I Googled this error message, but I only got two results and neither were related to iOS, so not very helpful. The exact same scripts are working fine for our other apps, but not for this one. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bundle ID on hockey app has to match the bundle ID of the app. If they don't, dSYM only uploads will not work. Took a while to figure this out, since the error message was quite misleading and when uploading the full ipa, the bundle ID doesn't have to match. Also, the mismatch was a typo and completely unintentional.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue once. Short answer: download dSyms from iTunes to your archive but don't delete existing dSym files. When downloaded, upload them all to Hockey.

Here is solution for my issue: https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/61441-issues-while-uploading-dsym-for-bitcode-enabled-ios-app